# E_strict error saving records after php upgrade

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using a script in codeigniter to save a record and after upgrading php it is producing an e_strict error.

Code:

```
function save($cdata){
        foreach($cdata as $key=>$value){
            $t=explode("_",$key);
            if($t[0]!="con"){
                $data->$key = setStringContent($value);
            }
        }
```

The error seems to be coming from this line

`$data->$key = setStringContent($value);`

Any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: What is setStringContent in your code?

Comment: you was upgrade from version to version?

Comment: It was PHP 5.3 to 5.4.

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: PHP Error was Severity: Warning

Message: Creating default object from empty value

Comment: What is $data? Where are you initialising it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not initialising $data anywhere you need to add this line before assigning values to it (somewhere before the foreach statement):

```
$data = new stdClass;
```

If it's an array then you should change that line to:

```
$data[$key] = setStringContent($value);
```